# Why does my text not show when i click on my navbar toggle button?

Tags: html, toggle, bootstrap-5

My navbar toggle is working accordingly but fails to show my text inputted when i click on it. The button works but the text inside the button isn't visible.

I tried checking the bootstrap docs to see if i'm missing any steps but i can't find any fault

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">TinDog</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" role="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are including the required bootstrap.js file, without it the button does nothing except respond to viewport width.
Next, since you used `.navbar-dark`, the text color is white; you need to make sure it has a dark background color in order to read the text. In the following snippet I added `.bg-dark`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">TinDog</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" role="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

### Note:

I also corrected your misuse of `.ml-auto` in BS5+ it's `.ms-auto` (s for start, e for end) to support both LTR & RTL text directions.